# Op-amp - dual to Single supply conversion to avoid floating of input signal?

Tags: operational-amplifier, embedded, automotive, voltage-measurement, vlsi

I'm designing a voltage measurement adaptor. And my signals are PWM type which ranges from 0-36V. I thought of using Op-amp to step down to 0-5V range and use an ADC to convert analog signals into digital.

To have a gain of <1,i'm using an inverting Op-amp (LT1630) where I can have split supply of (+18V to -18V) but then I have problem of connecting my input signal to a common ground zero(to avoid floating of input signal), so is it possible to give -36V at negative reference and ground the positive reference ?

LTspice simulation gives expected output (Gain of less than 1) with -18V at negative reference and Grounded positive reference for 36V input.  How is that possible? [image]

Comment: You can just use a voltage divider (2 resistors). What is the input impedance of your ADC - don't you want to get the average value? if so, add a capacitor. If not, you only need a digital input not an ADC.

Comment: I'm very confused on what you are doing with all those voltages, I'd just use a simple voltage divider and if needed an opamp buffer behind it. If you want to get a PWM signal input, you can just use a digital input, probably one of a timer-counter module to decode it.

Comment: @Arsenal : In my measurement environment, I’m not supposed to use voltage divider, because DUT i use in my test environment will misunderstand divider resistor of measurement adaptor as load. I chose opamp because of its very high input resistance.

Comment: @JayaramVignesh your very high input resistance is currently at 34kOhm. You'll need a buffering opamp first, but if you have it buffered, you can then use a resistor divider. How small is the current to be detected as a load?

Comment: @Arsenal Thanks for your idea of using buffer.

Current should not be more than few micro amps. In my circuit, i would connect an ADC next to Op-Amp which has got very high input resistance, so that current flow in the circuit is very much restricted.

My doubt is that, do supply rails of Op-Amp can decide only the range of input voltage or the range along with sign(+-). Because in my above circuit i have given supply only to -ve reference but the voltage input between 0-36V and it worked.How?

Comment: Probably because the simulation doesn't tell you, that your part would die. Have you looked at the currents in your simulation? I guess there are some bigger than they should be. The part you want to use has only a supply voltage range of 30V, 36V is the absolute maximum rating, and you don't want to design a circuit to those limits, so you better select a different part.

Comment: @Arsenal  Ok. i will look for a better Part. And in a circuit with input ranges from 0 to 36V for an Inverting Op-Amp(given  +-18V max rail to rail voltage specification) with supply rails connected to Gnd(0V) and -36V, will it work?

Comment: I don't get why you want to reverse the supply voltages. No it will not work, the applied voltages must be within the supply voltages, so if you have V+ at GND and V- at -36V your inputs must be between GND and -36V, otherwise the protection diodes will be active. And the output of the opamp can also only swing between GND and -36V then.

Comment: @Arsenal if I want to use input of 0-36V range, then how should my supplies be like? +- 18 V dual supply or 0 to -36V single supply for an Inverting Op-Amp?

Answer (score 1):

Inverting Op-Amp with gain < 1 will always tend to give output only in negative polarity and for that it draw power from negative supply of Op-Amp.If we use Single supply Opamp negative supply line of Op-Amp is grounded and output will be zero or low positive voltage.

We can attenaute positive voltages using inverting Op-Amp with dual supply as given in the picture using extra reference voltage Vref.[image]